# How values should be formatted before sending to the blockchain

Tags: ethers.js

Hello I'm receiving hexadecimal values like this `"0x1bc16d674ec80000"` and this `"0x40610"` and having issues to pass them in the transaction, how they should look like

Comment: Which values are these, in which fields? The `value` field is always an integer - unless you use some weird library

Answer (score 0):

You can try send them in BigNumber(from ethers) format or I think if you try send in hexadecimal format that will work

If you can't please show for us what error you got